# In SQL Server 2008 R2, is there a way to create a custom auto increment identity field without using IDENTITY(1,1)?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, auto-increment

I would like to be able to pull the custom key value from a table, but would also like it to perform like SQL Server's `IDENTITY(1,1)` column on inserts.

The custom key is for another application and will need to be used by different functions so the value will need to be pulled from a table and available for other areas.

Here are some if my attempts:

1. Tried a trigger on the table works well on single inserts, failed on using SQL insert (forgetting the fact that a triggers are not per row but by batch)

```
ALTER TRIGGER [sales].[trg_NextInvoiceDocNo] 
ON [sales].[Invoice]
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ResultVar VARCHAR(25)
    DECLARE @Key VARCHAR(25)

    EXEC [dbo].[usp_GetNextKeyCounterChar] 
               @tcForTbl = 'docNbr', @tcForGrp = 'docNbr', @NewKey =      @ResultVar OUTPUT

    UPDATE sales.InvoiceRET
    SET DocNbr = @ResultVar
    FROM sales.InvoiceRET
    JOIN inserted ON inserted.id = sales.InvoiceRET.id;
END;
```

2. Thought about a scalar function, but functions cannot exec stored procedures or update statements in order to set the new key value in the lookup table.

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't SQL Server 2008 support sequences?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: `SEQUENCE` is a new feature in SQL Server **2012** only - not available in 2008 R2 (which is totally unsupported by now anyway and should be **upgraded** as soon as possible)

Comment: @marc_s: ah, thanks. I thought that was added earlier.

Comment: Can we use RowNumber() option in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` depending on the type of concurrency you are dealing with. Here is some sample data and a demo you can run locally.

```
-- Sample table
USE tempdb
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.sometable','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.sometable;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.sometable
(
  SomeId INT NULL,
  Col1   INT NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Stored Proc to insert data
CREATE PROC dbo.InsertProc @output BIT AS
BEGIN -- Your proc starts here
  INSERT dbo.sometable(Col1) 
  SELECT datasource.[value]
  FROM   (VALUES(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%100)) AS datasource([value]) -- simulating data from somewhere
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1),(1),(1)) AS x(x);

  WITH 
  id(MaxId) AS (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(t.SomeId),0) FROM dbo.sometable AS t),
  xx AS 
  (
    SELECT     s.SomeId, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))+id.MaxId, s.Col1, id.MaxId
    FROM       id     AS id
    CROSS JOIN dbo.sometable AS s
    WHERE      s.SomeId IS NULL
  )
  UPDATE xx SET xx.SomeId = xx.RN;

  IF @output = 1
  SELECT t.* FROM dbo.sometable AS t;
END
GO
```

Each time I run: `EXEC dbo.InsertProc 1;` it returns 3 more rows with the correct ID col. Each time I execute it, it adds more rows and auto-increments as needed.

```
SomeId   Col1
-------- ------
1        62
2        73
3        -17
```